# Commercial for a novel about a woman who jumps off a building and grows a pair of angel wings

Tags: story-identification, tv

I want to say 2008-2010.

The narrator is sitting in a chair and talks about a new novel. He looks like Nicolas Cage/Ben Stein. Then we see a woman jump off a tall building, grows a pair of angel wings, and flies off. The commercial has a red/black theme going.

I have been searching for it for years.

Comment: Nicolas Cage and Ben Stein are two very different people...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HAhp9MWqa4 is a match for the Ben Stein-ish person (Brad Meltzer) sitting in a chair, and discussing their novel, "Book of Fate", but there's no woman growing angel and leaping off of a building.

Comment: James Patterson did a number of promos for his Maximum Ride series, some with him presenting, some not.  Here's a link to one without:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2iEnLGTHIE

Comment: Another:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMMpHdddCgo

Comment: @DoscoJones - Should be posted as an answer...

Comment: Insufficient evidence

Comment: Are you looking for a commercial or for the novel advertised? What does "The commercial has a red/black theme going." mean? Is that the color scheme of the commercial?

Answer (score 3):

Writer [James Patterson](https://www.jamespatterson.com/landing-page/james-patterson-home/) sometimes does TV commercial promos for his new books.  He did a number of promos for his *Maximum Ride* series, some with him presenting, some not.

Arguments can be made for resemblance between Ben Stein and a 2010 version of Patterson.